# How to Derive String from Future<String> in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I wish to get a string so as to pass to the second activity in flutter from the async function below:

```
Future<String> getString() async {
    return await readFromFile("./abc.txt").toString();

}
```

My problem is getting hold of a string from the function above and use it inside onPressed() funtion, I want to navigate to the next page and wish to pass the string along to the next page.
Whenever I try doing this, it gives me something like 'instance of Future...' instead of the actual string.

Comment: Yout function return a future, you should await for it
String response = await getString();
So then pass the response string to the navigator

Comment: Thanks, I'd attempted this, but it's kind of ways too slow.

Comment: The slowness its caused by the readFile. Are you testing this over the emulator?

Comment: Yes, I am testing it with an emulator

Answer (score 1):

You can either split the assignment or add parenthesis, because right now you actually try to `await` on `toString`.

```
Future<String> getString() async {
  Something content = await readFromFile("./abc.txt");
  return content.toString();
}
```

```
Future<String> getString() async {
  return (await readFromFile("./abc.txt")).toString();
}
```